# Using python class with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

From what I read, it is best practice to wrap code for a GUI in a class. How do I do this? I have come up with the following code based on some examples I have looked at, but this does not work as apparently `DropdownMenu` isn't defined? I have used this function successfully without the class wrapping.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog
import os

class Window(tk.Frame):

  def DropdownMenu(options,status,name):
    optionFrame = tk.Frame(root)
    optionLabel = tk.Label(optionFrame)
    optionLabel["text"] = name
    optionLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
    var = StringVar(root)
    var.set(status)
    w = tk.OptionMenu(optionFrame, var, *options)
    w.pack(side=LEFT)
    optionFrame.pack()
    return w

  def __init__(self,parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    ndim_options = DropdownMenu(("1","2","3"),'-',"Number of dimensions")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = tk.Tk()
  Window(root).pack()
  root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call DropdownMenu (inside the class), use self ...

```
ndim_options = self.DropdownMenu((...
```

Comment: That has just given me another error - apparently DropdownMenu has acquired an extra argument from somewhere? `ndim_options = self.DropdownMenu(("1","2","3"),'-',"Number of indirect dimensions")
TypeError: DropdownMenu() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)`

Comment: This is `self` again, use `def DropdownMenu(self, options, status, name):`

Comment: That runs as far as `optionLabel.pack(side=LEFT)` but I then get the error `optionLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
NameError: global name 'LEFT' is not defined` ?

Comment: That's because you changed `from Tkinter import *` to `import Tkinter as tk`. LEFT is defined in Tkinter, so you should use `tk.LEFT` now. Same goes for StringVar.